# Как сделать документацию к функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, документация

- Как сделать документацию к функции?
- Как автоматически сохранить документацию в файл?
- Также как получить документацию из какой-либо
  функции?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Документировать функции очень важно. Это помогает не только узнать что делает функция, но и подсказывает какие именованые аргументы она принимает и что в следствии может возвращать.
Документировать функции очень просто. Просто и обращаться к документации каждой функции.

Чтобы создать описание функции, внутри функции перед её телом нужно сделать многострочный комментарий(делается он с помощью трёх знаков `'''`). Этот комментарий будет рассматриваться, как аттрибут `.__doc__` и будет появляться при вызове `help()`, но об этом чуть позже.

Давайте сделаем небольшую функцию:

```
def to_str_smth(smth, step=1):
    smth = str(smth)
    return smth[::step]
```

Функция есть, давайте сделаем к ней описание для тех, кто будет, например, импортировать модуль с ней.

```
def to_str_smth(smth, step=1):
    """
    to_str_smth(smth, step=1)
    Makes the input data string and return it sliced with step
    """
    smth = str(smth)
    return smth[::step]
```

Теперь вызовем нашу документацию:

```
print(to_str_smth.__doc__)
```

Документацию можно вызвать и с помощью команды help(), но тогда свернётся весь наш аутпут и откроется что-то типа подокна (если вы знакомы с редактором nano, то вам будет проще понять), из которого можно выйти, нажав q

```
help(to_str_smth)
```

Почему не вызывем документацию у to_str_smth(), указывая скобки? Потому что так функция затребует аргументы, если они обязательны. К тому же, таким образом мы можем вернуть документацию подфункции, если она указана в return.

Посмотрим, например, на эту функцию:

```
def plus(a, b):
    """
    plus(a, b)
    Return a + b, typed float
    """
    return float(a + b)
```

Давайте попробуем вывести на экран документацию для неё, указав скобки:

```
print(plus().__doc__)
```

Как мы видим, функция запросила аргументы. Теперь давайте попробуем их передать и снова вызывать документацию:

```
print(plus(2.3, 2.7).__doc__)
```

Не совсем то, что хотелось бы видеть...

Важно соблюдать одинаковое форматирование при написании документации, как и при написании кода. Ознакомиться с рекомендациями по тому, как стоит документировать функции и классы, можно в справке [PEP257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Кстати, всё, что заключённо между парой `'''` игнорируется интерпретатором и таким образом можно спрятать блоки кода при его тестах.

Если мы хотим сохранить документацию, сделать это можно с помощью программы, которая идёт в комплекте с Python под названием pydoc. Для каждой версии есть свой pydoc, так что убедитесь, что вы запускаете ту версию pydoc'а, иначе может возникнуть конфликт импорта модулей.

Сделать это можно следующим образом (подразумевается, что запуск идёт из директории с модулем):

```
pydoc3.6 -w ./mymodule # также подойдёт pydoc -w ./mymodule.py
```

Таким образом будет создан html файл с вашей документацией для модуля mymodule. Дизайн не очень, зато быстро. Для стартапов пойдёт. К тому же, помимо pydoc есть множество программ, которые генерируют документацию в файл. Вот некоторые из них:

1. HappyDoc
2. pudge
3. epydoc

Обращаясь к документации с помощью help() или `.__doc__`, мы можем разрешить множество вопросов, связанных с импортируемыми модулями, а документируя свой код - не забыть что он делает, возвращает и для чего он нужен спустя долгое время.

Comment: Зачем, пардон, Вы сами на свои вопросы отвечаете? ЗАчем их задавать тогда, если через минуту ответ готов? Рейтинг набивать?

Comment: @hedgehogues я поднимаю темы, которые считаю интересными сообществу и новчикам и которые ещё не поднимались. Вы также можете ответить, если хотите, никто не запрещает

Comment: Можно еще написать про разные форматы документации - numpy доки, google доки, доки из Pycharm. В общем Python регламентирует только местонахождение доков (в начала функции/метода, например), но не их формат (см. PEP 257, 287 - `docstring - string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition`). Еще бывает, что на месте документов оказывается [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html). Еще не лишним будет какой-нибудь инструмент по "очеловечиванию" документов, конвертацию их в какой-нибудь html, как на readthedocs

Comment: @hedgehogues если вопрос полезный и ответ грамотный, то только [приветствуется такая публикация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Хотя текущий вопрос почти  "слишком обширный" (или ответ не достаточно тему раскрывает и нет ссылок на более полное изложение темы адекватное широте вопроса (к примеру, можно упомянуть слово docstring, упомянуть рекомендации из pep 8, pep 257, упомянуть возможные форматы, pydoc, sphinx, reStructuredText, [итд](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3898572/4279)). По мелочи: string literal можно как комментарий использовать, но это не комментарий).

Comment: @jfs так лучше?

Comment: @hedgehogues Как уже сказано выше, самоответы не только не порицаются, но и приветствуются! Оценивайте вопросы и ответы без привязки к тому кто их (за)дает и его рейтингу. SO - про вопросы и ответы, а не про то кто их (за)дает.

Comment: Про pydoc и его альтернативы подробно рассказывается в 17 главе книги [**Pro Python Best Practice**](https://www.google.ru/search?q=pro+python+best+practice+download&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=XAbvWKTHA8KE6ATWl4b4AQ). Про `docstrings` то, что Вы расписали, я читал в 10 главе [**A Byte Of Python**](http://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/AByteofPythonRussian-2.01.pdf). Добавил бы ссылки на эти книги для тех, кто хочет узнать подробнее об ответах на Ваши вопросы. Спасибо.

Comment: @Kromster спасибо за форматирование вопроса