# Зачем нужен вызов "-> max(a,b)" при создании функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, python-faq

Нашёл такой пример:

```
def function(a:int,b:str,c:list) -> max(2,3):
```

Зачем используется `-> max(...)`?

Comment: А можно на код самой функции посмотреть?

Comment: Обычно через стрелку указывается тип возвращаемого значения функции ([аннотация типа](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484), на работу функции никак не влияет). Что имелось в виду в данном случае - не очень понятно.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Вкратце: он не нужен, это просто демонстрация использования аннотации. Вместо этого после стрелки нужно указывать тип возвращаемого значения функции.

---

В данной строке

```
def function(a:int,b:str,c:list) -> max(2,3):
```

`:int`, `:str`, `:list`, `-> max(2,3)` - это аннотации. Впервые они предлагаются к введению в Python в [PEP 3107](https://python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), но их назначение четко не регламентировалось (их интерпретация возлагалась на авторов сторонних инструментов).

Позже было более четко зафиксировано использование аннотаций как аннотаций типов ([PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484)), т.е. после аргументов функции через двоеточие пишем предполагаемый тип аргумента, после `->` пишем тип возвращаемого значения функции.

В качестве аннотации может использоваться *любое синтаксически верное выражение Python*. При запуске кода интерпретатором выражения, используемые в качестве аннотации, исполняются (поэтому могут вызывать ошибки во время исполнения, например выражение `def f() -> max(None, 1): pass` вызовет ошибку `TypeError`, пример от **jfs**), но никаким специальным образом интерпретатором не обрабатываются (т.е., например, интерпретатор сам не проверяет типы).

Опять же, интерпретатор их игнорирует, но аннотации типов могут использоваться такими инструментами как [mypy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/) или встроенным в [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) статическим анализатором кода, чтобы понимать, что в функцию передано (или возвращено) значение не того типа, которое предполагалось, и отображать это как ошибку или предупреждение.

`-> max(2,3)` с моей точки зрения не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки. Это не аннотация типа, а просто аннотация. Что имел в виду автор примера - загадка. Скорее всего это просто пример использования аннотаций.

Программно получить доступ к аннотациям функции можно через атрибут функции `__annotations__`:

```
def function(a:int,b:str,c:list) -> max(2,3): pass

print(function.__annotations__)
```

Результат:

```
{'a': <class 'int'>, 'return': 3, 'c': <class 'list'>, 'b': <class 'str'>}
```

Здесь видны прописанные для аргументов типы, и видно, что выражение `max(2,3)` вычислилось, поэтому в качестве аннотации для возвращаемого значения записалось просто 3.

Comment: недостаточно быть только "синтаксически верным", к примеру, `def f() -> max(None, 1): pass` ведёт к `TypeError`

Comment: @jfs, дополнил ответ.

Comment: @insolor, отличный ответ! Вы могли бы еще привести пример как можно динамически (програмно) воспользоваться данными аннотациями - например из внешней функции получить типы параметров?

Comment: @MaxU, дописал про доступ к аннотациям)

Comment: @insolor, спасибо!

Comment: Когда происходит вычисление максимума? Возможно ли в аннотацию запихнуть побочные эффекты?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в момент запуска скрипта. Побочные эффекты при желании можно впихнуть.

Comment: @insolor, именно скрипта? Не вызова функции?

Comment: @Qwertiy, именно скрипта. `def func(a) -> max(None, 1): pass` выдаст ошибку при запуске скрипта, до вызова функции. По крайней мере на Python 3.6 это так. На 3.7, 3.8 желательно протестировать, могло что-то поменяться.

Comment: @Qwertiy, на 3.8 все то же самое, ошибка в момент запуска скрипта.

Answer (score 2):

Как мы можем видеть, эта функция может принимать число - `a:int`, строку - `b:str` и список - `c:list`.

Функция `max()` возвращает наибольшее значение. Это можно узнать из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max)

Обычно после стрелки указывают возвращаемое значение. Посудив логически, можно предположить, что данная функция обрабатывает 2 каких-то типа. То есть **`int` и `list`** или **`str` и `list`**. Либо же просто сравнивает 2 числа или 2 строки. И возвращает наибольшее значение из переданных данных. Но это не точно. То есть в общем виде функция может выглядеть примерно так:

```
def function(a, b):
    if type(b) == list:
        lst = b[:] # или b.copy()
        lst.append(a)
        try:
            return max(lst)
        except ValueError:
            return "'>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"
    else:
        try:
            return max(a, b)
        except ValueError:
            return "'>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"
```

То есть если мы передадим, например, число `5` и список из чисел `[3, 7, 1, 0, 4, 2, -1, 8, -4]`, то функция вернёт нам наибольшее значение из переданных данных, то есть **8**.

При вызове, например, этой функции с числом `20` и этим же списком, на выходе мы получим число **20**, так как оно больше, чем какое-либо из списка.

Что конкретно всё же имелось ввиду в данном случае - не очень понятно. Такой тип написания документации к функции очень плох, ибо не раскрывает цели функции, а также не сообщает что и при каких условиях функция возвращает. Подробнее о документировании классов и функций можно узнать, перейдя по этой [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652572/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/652575#652575).